# Word for adding greenery to a barren landscape

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word similar to "rewilding" and "reforestation/afforestation" used to describe adding greenery to a barren landscape. I think it might be related to the word "verdure", but I'm not sure. It's on the tip of my tongue. Does anyone know it?

Comment: Example sentence?

Comment: William Caxton used the verb *verdoying* to mean waxing green in his translation of Ovid’s *Metamorphoses*, from the [French verb *verdoyer*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verdoyer#French): *“A grene medowe full of herbes **verdoying** or wexyng grene.”* But today the word *verdoy* sees little currency as a verb, having been relegated to [the formal language of heraldry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verdoy) and demoted from its verbness. I suspect this was not the word that had been on the tip of your tongue here, but I’m quite willing to be wrong about that suspicion. :)

Answer (score 1):

**re-greening** (MW)<sup>**1**</sup>

> transitive verb. : to make green again especially : to restore (barren, degraded, or deforested land) to a healthy ecological state by planting vegetation (such as trees, shrubs, grasses, or sustainable crops) often in conjunction with improvements in soil fertility and water retention …

*Usage:*

> Environmentalists are trying to minimise the damage through a climate adaptation programme involving communities farming at over 3,000 metres to regreen the denuded mountains.
>   ([Fragile Land](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Fragile+Land-a0372322763)) Copyright 2014 The Killid Group

<sup>**1**</sup> *meta:* Some issues with the MW site from this terminal, so not providing a link right now. See instead the [ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regreen):

> verb
>   *with object* To make green again; especially to re-establish plant growth.
>   Origin: Early 17th century; earliest use found in Joshua Sylvester (d. 1618), poet and translator. From re- + green.